# How to pass discriminated union to function

Tags: f#

I have the discriminated union:

```
type Attribute =
    | AttrA of o : AttrA
    | AttrB of o : AttrB
    // ...
    | None
```

And I have the big piece of code which I want to refactore:

```
  // get Attribute
  match someType with 
  | 0 ->  let attrs  = foo1 name
           match attrs.Length with
           | 0 -> None
           | _ -> AttrA(o = attrs.[0] )

   | 1 ->  let attrs  = foo2 name
            match attrs.Length with
            | 0 -> None
            | _ -> AttrB(o = attrs.[0] )

    // ...
```

I want to create new function to use it in the inner match.  Here is what I have:

```
let foo (f : (string -> 'b[])) (s : string) (t :  Attribute) =
    let attrs  = f s
     match attrs.Length with
    | 0 -> None
    | _ -> t(o = attrs.[0])
```

The problem with parameter `t`.

> It is not a function and can not be applied.

How can I fix my function ?

Comment: You cannot use parameter name `t` to construct object of type `Attribute`. You should use one of the case names

Comment: Can you please give a little example how to "use one of the case names" ?

Comment: `AttrA()`, `AttrB()`  etc. As compiler said `t` is not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
let foo (f : (string -> 'b[])) (s : string) (make : 'b -> Attribute) =
    let attrs  = f s
    match attrs.Length with
    | 0 -> None
    | _ -> make(attrs.[0])
```

`make` can be a regular function or it can be a type constructor, i.e. `Attribute.AttrA`.

Comment: Note that you could rewrite this function to work without parameter annotation, by using `Array.length` and `Array.get` instead of a property and indexer. The compiler then infers the signature as `val foo : f:('a -> 'b []) -> s:'a -> make:('b -> Attribute) -> Attribute`, which is slightly more generic.